# How to auto-close Vim window in terminal?

Tags: git, vim, terminal, zsh, rebase

I am trying to speed up the workflow and created an alias in `~/.zshrc`:

`alias update='git fetch origin; git rebase -i origin/master'`

But the problem is, it will obviously open up the Vim window to ask me if I want to pick/edit/squash the commits.

I want to make life easier for myself. So I want to add something to this line that would auto-close the Vim window.

I already asked ChatGPT to give me the answer, it told me this:

`git fetch origin; git rebase -i origin/master; vim -c "bd|q!"`

I tested, it failed. It cannot auto-close the Vim window.

Comment: Why do you start an interactive rebase if you don't want to do an interactive rebase?

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to autosquash the commits without having an editor window opened, then the easiest way to do that is this:

```
GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR=true git rebase -i --autosquash BASE
```

As an alias, that looks like this:

```
[alias]
    srebase = "!f() { GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR=true git rebase -i --autosquash \"$@\"; };f"
```

The problem with your command is that the Vim command isn't executed until after the rebase completes, and the rebase doesn't complete until your editor returns.  In any event, the Vim command wouldn't interact with any other Vim already open even if it were run at the same time, since you haven't used the client-server protocol, and it's not known whether your version is even compiled that way.

However, if you want to do something fancy that involves editing the contents of the interactive rebase, then you can use the `GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR` environment variable to provide a command (taking one argument, the sequence file) that modifies the sequence file in place.  That environment variable can accept an arbitrary shell script (for `/bin/sh` and `/bin/sh` only), since it will be passed to the shell, just like any other editor configuration.